# Why create a service (factory/creator) instead of do that in the Controller?

Tags: php, laravel

In a Laracasts tutorial I see this:

- `app/controller/TasksController`
- `app/Acme/Services/TaskCreatorService`

The `TasksController` has this method:

```
public function store()
{
    // ...
    $this->TaskCreator->make(Input::all());
    // ...
}
```

And in the `TaskCreatorService` the method `make` validate and create the Task.

What is this methodology and why Jeffrey Way did it?

Why not **create a task directly in the controller**?

---

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: Because using a factory in this way allows you to mock the task object returned from the factory for test purposes

Comment: Hmmm, so this is a good pratice for testing?

Comment: Among other things such as separation of concerns.  Check out `Laravel: From Apprentice to Artisan` when you get a chance.  It should make these types of practices much more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually about [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which is:

> Dependency injection is a software design pattern in which one or more
>   dependencies (or services) are injected, or passed by reference, into
>   a dependent object (or client) and are made part of the client's
>   state. The pattern separates the creation of a client's dependencies
>   from its own behavior, which allows program designs to be [loosely
>   coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) and to follow the [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and [single
>   responsibility principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In this case it's part of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. In `SOLID` the `Dependency inversion principle` states that `one should "Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions."`

**Advantages of dependency injection:**

- Because dependency injection doesn't require any change in code behavior it can be applied to legacy code as a refactoring. The result is more independent clients that are easier to unit test in isolation using stubs or mock objects that simulate other objects not under test. This ease of testing is often the first benefit noticed when using dependency injection.
- Dependency injection allows a client to remove all knowledge of a concrete implementation that it needs to use. This helps isolate the client from the impact of design changes and defects. It promotes reusability, testability and maintainability.
- Dependency injection can be used to externalize a system's configuration details into configuration files allowing the system to be reconfigured without recompilation. Separate configurations can be written for different situations that require different implementations of components. This includes, but is not limited to, testing.
- Reduction of boilerplate code in the application objects since all work to initialize or set up dependencies is handled by a provider component.
- Dependency injection allows concurrent or independent development. Two developers can independently develop classes that use each other, while only needing to know the interface the classes will communicate through. Plugins are often developed by third party shops that never even talk to the developers who created the product that uses the plugins. ***(Ref:wikipedia)***.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I suggest the section under "Advantages of dependency injection:" be quoted or more clearly mentioned that it's from another source. :)